# Specify filename when using httr to POST file in R

Tags: r, post, httr

Trying to upload a datafile from R using `httr` `POST`.  The following almost works but I need to specify the filename, e.g. `"mydata.csv"`.  How do I specify the filename?  It's blank when it reaches the server.

```
POST(uri, body=list(y=upload_file(filename)))
```

In `curl` one would specify it with a `-F name=filename` as in :

```
curl -i -F name=test -F filedata=@localfile.jpg http://example.org/upload
```

[How to POST multipart/related content with httr (for Google Drive API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080363/how-to-post-multipart-related-content-with-httr-for-google-drive-api)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-F` flag allows you to pass additional form values with your POST. You can do that with `httr` by just adding more named elements to the body list.

```
POST("http://example.org/upload", body=list(name="test.csv", filedata=upload_file(filename, "text/csv")))
```

Comment: Awesome. And if you want to send 3 attachments?