# Object not found error while piping in R

Tags: r, tidyr, recode

I am trying to recode the values of mixed alpha-number character variable with a data set I am running through pipes in R. I have loaded the following packages:

- tidyverse
- tidyr
- dplyr
- lubridate
- forcats

My original dataset consisted of 4 obs. of 325 variables. I changed the format and now have 1296 obs. of 3 variables:

- ID
- month_year
- value

Some sample data:

ID |  month_year | value

----| ----| ----|

LA01 | Jan.1990 | 3.5

----| ----| ----|

LA02 | Jan.1990 | 195294.0

---- | ---- | ---- |

LA03 | Jan.1990 | 434343.0

---- | ---- | ---- |

LA01 | Feb.1990 | 3.0

---- | ---- | ---- |

LA02 | Feb.1990 | 195234.0

---- | ---- | ---- |

LA03 | Feb.1990 | 43325.0

---- | ---- | ---- |

Some sample output from a glimpse call for my data:
My data:

```
> Observations: 1,296 
Variables: 3 
$ Series.ID  <fctr>
> LAUMT064186000000003, LAUMT064186000000004, LAUMT064186000000005,
> LAUM... 

$ month_year <chr> "Jan.1990", "Jan.1990", "Jan.1990",
> "Jan.1990", "Feb.1990", "Feb.1990",... 

$ value      <dbl> 3.5,
> 70296.0, 1952945.0, 2023241.0, 3.3, 66517.0, 1948964.0, 2015481.0,...
```

**Problem to Solve**
I want to change the name of the values for "ID" (aka Series.ID). There are 4 values I have tried to change in my data frame, "tidier_labor", using:

```
tidier_labor %>%
  mutate(Series.ID = fct_recode(Series.ID, unemployment_rate = "LAUMT064186000000003", unemployment = "LAUMT064186000000004", employment = "LAUMT064186000000005", labor_force = "LAUMT064186000000006"))
```

However I receive an error message reading

> ‘Series.ID’ converted to character stringError in as.environment(pos)
>   :    no item called "Series.ID" on the search list

It's possible that I need to make some kind of transformation so that my variables can be identified, but I am at a loss of how to do this. I have tried using 'as.character' or 'as.factor' but while the output may show the the data was transformed, when I use 'View' to look over my dataset, nothing has changed.

Any help would be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the class() of tidier_labor?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356834/how-to-post-multipart-binary-non-binary-with-httr-for-salesforce-api) with sample input data. Also, this site works best if you post one clear question at a time. If you have two questions, start two posts.

Comment: The class of tidier_labor is a data frame.